# Rotate a child element while clicking its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do an animated transformation in the arrows of a button, every time I click on it.
The idea is to rotate 180 degrees each side of the arrow (which are made of divs) every time someone clicks on the div that contains these divs that forms the arrows.

I tried with Toggle but didn´t work. Here is my code:

```css
.button-back {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-back:hover {
  background-color: #2da6ff;
}

.left {
  left: 5%;
}

.right {
  right: 5%;
}

#left-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#left-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#right-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 40%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

#right-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 40%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-back left">
  <div id="left-top"></div>
  <div id=left-bottom></div>
</div>
<div class="button-back right">
  <div id="right-top"></div>
  <div id="right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to make a rotation animation (180) on click ?

Comment: Yes, but it´s a little bit more difficult than that. The buttons are made with three divs (the background, the top of the arrow and the bottom of the arrow). What I want to do is that when you click on the back, the top of the arrow rotates +180 and the bottom of the arrow rotates -180 at the same time. Here you can see what I mean (check out the buttons of the slider): https://codepen.io/suez/pen/grJONP

Comment: that's more clear to understand :) check my solution bellow i made looks exactly the same as the codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution
I added an animated class so that the element with make the rotation animation slowly in 0.5sec

```
.animated {
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

and then i made a script to handle the rotation of each arrow line

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var leftdegplus = -45;
  var leftdegminus = 45;
  var rightdegplus = 45;
  var rightdegminus = -45;
  $(".left").click(function() {
    leftdegplus = leftdegplus + 180;
    $(this).find("#left-top").css("transform", "rotate(" + leftdegplus + "deg)");

    leftdegminus = leftdegminus - 180;
    $(this).find("#left-bottom").css("transform", "rotate(" + leftdegminus + "deg)");

  });
  $(".right").click(function() {

    rightdegplus = rightdegplus - 180;
    $(this).find("#right-top").css("transform", "rotate(" + rightdegplus + "deg)");

    rightdegminus = rightdegminus + 180;
    $(this).find("#right-bottom").css("transform", "rotate(" + rightdegminus + "deg)");
  });


});
```

This is the full code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var leftdegplus = -45;
  var leftdegminus = 45;
  var rightdegplus = 45;
  var rightdegminus = -45;
  $(".left").click(function() {
    leftdegplus = leftdegplus + 180;
    $(this).find("#left-top").css("transform", "rotate(" + leftdegplus + "deg)");

    leftdegminus = leftdegminus - 180;
    $(this).find("#left-bottom").css("transform", "rotate(" + leftdegminus + "deg)");

  });
  $(".right").click(function() {

    rightdegplus = rightdegplus - 180;
    $(this).find("#right-top").css("transform", "rotate(" + rightdegplus + "deg)");

    rightdegminus = rightdegminus + 180;
    $(this).find("#right-bottom").css("transform", "rotate(" + rightdegminus + "deg)");
  });


});
```

```css
.button-back {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-back:hover {
  background-color: #2da6ff;
}

.left {
  left: 5%;
}

.right {
  right: 5%;
}

#left-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#left-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#right-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 40%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

#right-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 40%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

.animated {
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-back left">
  <div class="animated " id="left-top"></div>
  <div class="animated " id=left-bottom></div>
</div>
<div class="button-back right">
  <div class="animated " id="right-top"></div>
  <div class="animated " id="right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You welcome :) it took me a lot of time since i hate maths haha

Comment: @Santiago can you validate the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this))

```js
let left = document.querySelector('.left');
let arrows = left.children;

function removeRotate(){
  arrows[0].classList.remove('rotate-top');
  arrows[1].classList.remove('rotate-bottom');
}

function rotate(){
  arrows[0].classList.add('rotate-top');
  arrows[1].classList.add('rotate-bottom');
  setTimeout(removeRotate, 200);
}

left.addEventListener('click', rotate);
```

```css
.button-back {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-back:hover {
  background-color: #2da6ff;
}

.left {
  left: 5%;
}


#left-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#left-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}


.rotate-top{
  animation: rotate-center-top 0.3s linear both;
}
.rotate-bottom{
  animation: rotate-center-bottom 0.3s linear both;
}


@keyframes rotate-center-top {
  0% {
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {

            transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-center-bottom {
  0% {
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
            transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button-back left">
  <div id="left-top"></div>
  <div id=left-bottom></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to use javascript for this

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");

var right = document.getElementById("right");

left.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  if (e.target.id !== "left") return;

  e.target.children["0"].style.transition = "0.3s transform linear";

  e.target.children["1"].style.transition = "0.3s transform linear";

  e.target.children["0"].style.transform = "rotate(140deg)";

  e.target.children["1"].style.transform = "rotate(-140deg)";

  setTimeout(function() {

    e.target.children["0"].style.transition = "0s all linear";

    e.target.children["1"].style.transition = "0s all linear";

    e.target.children["0"].removeAttribute("style");

    e.target.children["1"].removeAttribute("style");

  }, 510);

});

right.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  if (e.target.id !== "right") return;

  e.target.children["0"].style.transition = "0.3s transform linear";

  e.target.children["1"].style.transition = "0.3s transform linear";

  e.target.children["0"].style.transform = "rotate(-140deg)";

  e.target.children["1"].style.transform = "rotate(140deg)";

  setTimeout(function() {

    e.target.children["0"].style.transition = "0s all linear";

    e.target.children["1"].style.transition = "0s all linear";

    e.target.children["0"].removeAttribute("style");

    e.target.children["1"].removeAttribute("style");

  }, 510);

});
```

```css
.button-back {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-back:hover {
  background-color: #2da6ff;
}

.left {
  left: 5%;
}

.right {
  right: 5%;
}

#left-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#left-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 30%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  z-index: 3;
}

#right-top {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 40%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

#right-bottom {
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 40%;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-back left" id="left">
  <div id="left-top"></div>
  <div id=left-bottom></div>
</div>
<div class="button-back right" id="right">
  <div id="right-top"></div>
  <div id="right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```